# How to call Observer method in controller in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, controllers

I need to call function in observer by controller function. How I do this. Please explain with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a controller anywhere with

```
$controller = Mage::getControllerInstance(
'The_Controller_Class',
Mage::app()->getRequest(),
Mage::app()->getResponse());
```

To tell if this is the best way, I would need to know more about your use case

Comment: welcome, happy to help :)

Comment: @ShakirKhan How can we do the same on Magento 2? Can you please help?